# Altium - short-circuit between pad and poly-region with same net

Tags: altium

I draw a grounded trace BLE Antenna.

One pad has the GND Net and the second pad is ANT Net

[image]

Here is the error:

> Class Document    Source  Message Time    Date    No. [Short-Circuit Constraint Violation]    control-board-v8.PcbDoc Advanced PCB    Short-Circuit Constraint: Between Pad E1-GND(1300mil,3326.176mil) on Top And Region (0 hole(s)) Top Location : [X = 1299.983mil][Y = 3332.018mil]   7:32:55 PM  6/13/2019   1

[image]

and here are my short-circuit rules :

[image]

the proof that my pad and polygon got the right NET (GND) :
PAD:
[image]
POLY:
[image]

How can I get rid of this error ?

**PS: I already ran the t,g,a (Tools -> polygon pour -> Repour All)**

Comment: You need to declare the antenna footprint to be a "Net Tie".

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks a lot! it works like a charm!